# Copying and paste from Wine program to terminal doesn't work

Tags: 16.04, wine

I'm using wine-1.6.2 in Ubuntu 16 LTS and when I copy text from Notepad++ and attempt to paste it into the terminal it doesn't work. I can do the same thing with gedit and it works (gedit > select text > right-click > copy , terminal > right-click > paste)

How can I copy and paste from a Wine program into the terminal, why doesn't what I copied go to the clipboard?

Comment: Does it paste in other programs other than Terminal. Also, to paste in terminal you need to press Ctrl + Shift + V instead of Ctrl + V.

Comment: That works. It was the right-click menu where I chose paste that didn't work (the old clipboard stuff was still there), but now it's working. So I guess there is a bug somewhere.

Comment: I have added it as an answer, mark it as accepted so that the question does not appear in unanswered section.

Comment: I've marked that as the answer since technically it's correct. Also I've filed at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wine1.6/+bug/1616710

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try pasting it using key combination `Ctrl + Shift + V`. This works in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

I found I'm able to copy from N++ using `Ctrl + Ins` or `Ctrl + C`, paste into a non-WINE app (e.g. Text Editor, or Chrome's address bar if it's single-line), then copy again from there, after which `Shift + Ins` or `Ctrl + V` will paste into Terminal.  Not as neat as Ceda El's answer (which also works with Ctrl-Shift-Ins), but might be useful to some.

Interestingly, you can use this "feature" to give yourself two paste buffers.

- `Ctrl + V` (and aliases) will paste whatever was copied from native apps
- `Ctrl + Shift + V`will paste whatever was copied from N++